# What's the difference between Optimal ate pairing and R-ate pairing?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings, bilinear-pairing

I compare the algorithm description of Optimal ate pairing and R-ate pairing, it turns out to me that the formulas are the same. So I'm a little confused, what's the difference between them? or is it just I misunderstand? Thanks very much.

[image]

ref: Beuchat J L, González-Díaz J E, Mitsunari S, et al. High-speed software implementation of the optimal ate pairing over Barreto–Naehrig curves[C]//International Conference on Pairing-Based Cryptography. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2010: 21-39.
[image]

ref: SM9 identity-based cryptographic algorithms Part 1: General Page32-33 http://www.gmbz.org.cn/upload/2018-04-04/1522794739303068173.pdf